# "npm install -g express-generator" using this command on Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: node.js, mongodb

> npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@^1.0.0 (node_modules/nodemon/node_modules/chokidar/node_modules/fsevents):
>   npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@1.1.1: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"linux","arch":"x64"})

`npm ERR! Linux 4.4.0-62-generic
npm ERR! argv "/usr/bin/nodejs" "/usr/local/bin/npm" "install" "nodemon" "-g"
npm ERR! node v4.2.6
npm ERR! npm  v4.2.0
npm ERR! path /usr/local/lib/node_modules
npm ERR! code EACCES
npm ERR! errno -13
npm ERR! syscall access`

> npm ERR! Error: EACCES: permission denied, access '/usr/local/lib/node_modules'
>   npm ERR!     at Error (native)
>   npm ERR!  { [Error: EACCES: permission denied, access '/usr/local/lib/node_modules']
>   npm ERR!   errno: -13,
>   npm ERR!   code: 'EACCES',
>   npm ERR!   syscall: 'access',
>   npm ERR!   path: '/usr/local/lib/node_modules' }
>   npm ERR! 
>   npm ERR! Please try running this command again as root/Administrator.

`npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR!     /home/santosh/.npm/_logs/2017-02-23T05_20_16_087Z-debug.log`

Comment: please tell me how to resolve this problem........

Comment: [Read How to ask on Stackoverflow](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) before posting a query

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask. Also see [Where do I post questions about Dev Ops?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/134306)

Answer (score 2):

use `sudo npm install -g express-generator`

Comment: sudo npm install -g express-generator , after using this command i am getting same error what i posted. @pok8

Answer (score 0):

Try to run the npm command with **sudo** or follow the steps provided in this video: https://docs.npmjs.com/all#fixing-npm-permissions